# Can JavaScript function call subexpressions be tail calls?

Tags: javascript, tail-recursion, tail-call-optimization

Consider the following return statement:

```js
return f() || g();
```

The call `f()` obviously is not a tail call, because the function does not actually return if `f()` is falsy.

What about the `g()` part though, is that a tail call? Or do I have to rewrite it like this:

```js
const temp = f();
if (temp) return temp; else return g();
```

Comment: Try it and see?  "Do I have to ..." <= easy enough to test the different cases to see if you "have to"

Comment: It doesn't matter in practice. Only Safari actually supports tail call optimization, no matter what the standard says.

Comment: JS coders shouldn't worry about implementation details, which frequently change anyway; what's the actual problem/question here?

Comment: @dandavis: It matters for tail call elimination.

Comment: @dandavis: Tail call elimination allows program designs that don't work without tail call elimination. It's not an implementation detail.

Comment: @dandavis I just want to make sure `function generate() { return attempt() || generate(); }` does not blow the call stack.

Comment: fair enough, but I wouldn't count on it anytime soon.

Comment: @dandavis: It's standard-mandated, but support is terrible.

Comment: I would think if you want to make sure you do not blow the stack you need to work in logic to account for a max recursion count.  For instance you could pass the count into generate, default it to zero, and increment it on each subsequent call.  Once it reaches whatever number you deem too much, stop the nested calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but it doesn't help in practice.

According to the [standard](https://262.ecma-international.org/10.0/#sec-expression-rules), `g()` is in tail position:

> LogicalORExpression : LogicalORExpression || LogicalANDExpression
>
> Return HasCallInTailPosition of LogicalANDExpression with argument call.

However, most browsers [don't support](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/) tail call elimination, and the Chromium team isn't working on it, so you can't rely on tail call elimination in practice no matter how you write your tail calls.

Answer (score 1):

> Try it and see?

For some reason that didn't occur to me in my sleep-deprived state :D

```js
function f() {
    return Math.random() > 1 || f();
}

f()
```

Node says `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`, Firefox says `InternalError: too much recursion`.

Comment: That's because those engines don't support tail call elimination at all.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Even though ES6 mandates it? TIL

Comment: no, `Math.random() will never return > 1` - always false, so `f()` is called forever

Comment: @RandyCasburn I deliberately chose a condition that is always false for this experiment. With tail call optimization, the infinite recursion would not blow the stack but just loop forever.

Comment: Ah, of course, got it. What @user2357112supportsMonica - says then :-)